# Facebook Mobile - Photo Sharing To Multiple Lists

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-timeline, facebook-integration, facebook-photos

Can someone please explain to me how I can share photos on Facebook mobile with multiple lists or groups? It seems that I am only able to choose one list to share with. From a computer you can set it up to share with specific lists (more than 1). I would love to know how to do this from the mobile platform.